# C# Gridview Data is there but it does not render on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that I'm working on, and I have gotten gridviews to populate before. However this time, I can't seem to get it to display.  I've gone through the debugger and am able to validate that the bind works and data is stored in the Gridview.  I just can't see it on the page.

HTML:

```
 <asp:GridView 
    ID="gvData"
    runat="server"   
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"
    ViewStateMode="Enabled">
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Code:

```
try
{
    gvData.DataSource = GridData;
    gvData.DataBind();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}

lblParameterSpecs.Text = gvData.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

I have the label as a test and the label returns the proper value, but the grid just does not appear on the page.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Again, I was able to confirm that gridview.databind() did lock in the data into the gridview as it can be seen from the label text, but the gridview is blank.  and when I inspect the page, the gridview element is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Because of your catch statement it seems you are messing with the Response, I think you should give more info, what is the method doing the DataBind() etc.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  The button that called the procedure to populate the gridview was located inside and ASP:UpdatePanel tag.  The label where I could see the data was also located inside that tag.  The gridview itself was not.

I forgot to add the postbacktrigger within the tag:

```
                          <asp:UpdatePanel runat ="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                              <Triggers>
                                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExecSP" />
                              </Triggers>
```

Comment: Adding a post-backtrigger will not change this unless the GV is in some other panel. However, by default, all panels get posted back to the server unless you set the UP updatemode as conditional. Without a conditional, then ALL panels are posted. And setting a post-back trigger in the same panel that has the button? Not required. Post-back triggers are to trigger OTHER UP's on the page - not the one that already has a button that will and does cause a post-back.  Now on the other hand, the big whopper in the room would be that the GV was also in a UP panel - which I would assume it was.

Comment: I believe it was.  After I added the trigger the data populated as expected.  Thank you for the reply.